# What is the smallest body of water I can fish from?

Tags: terraria

As I jet about Terraria, trying to fish, I find that some bodies of water don't seem to be large enough to fish from.

Whether they are too shallow or just too small I do not know; so therein lies the question:

What are the dimensions required of a body of liquid in Terraria to make it fish-able?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 75 tiles of OPEN water. Note that any water that touches the ceiling and all vertically beneath it is not counted - I tested with the [fisherman's pocket guide](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Fisherman%27s_Pocket_Guide). But note that you will have a penalty on your fishing power which reduces until the water is 300 tiles in total.

Note that the requirement does not calculate the exact amount of tiles filled with water - having 50 tiles wide of 1.5 tiles of water can be a valid fishing area.

On earlier phases where larger water bodies might not spawn near you base you can drain nearby pools of water to a open area under your base as an early game fishing area. Which you can later lower by digging it's base to make it a cavern/underground fishing area.

Answer (score 4):

I believe from what I've picked up, that the minimum number of 'blocks' of water needed to fish is about 70 (total number of 'blocks': e.g. a 7 by 10 block lake; this is about the smallest I've been able to catch anything in), with 300+ being optimal (i.e. no penalties).
To be taken with a grain of salt as this is mostly derived from anecdotal evidence.

Comment: Do you mean 70 long, deep or total collected, any shape?

Comment: @Sharain almost certainly total.

Comment: What 'penalties' are there?

Comment: @Sharain yes I meant total blocks, i.e. a 7 by 10 lake for example. Edit: fixed in my answer for clarity

Comment: @Jonah Bishop There should be a falloff on the amount and rarity of the things you catch, going down to nothing at all when you get below the stated minimum size. No idea what the exact numbers are though.

Answer (score 0):

To not fish junk, you'll want a lake with at least 300 blocks of water.  I usually achieve this by digging a 10x30 hole and using the water duping bug to fill it.